# How can I create a large Metro calendar?

Tags: .net, windows-8, calendar, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to make an app that features, among other things, a calendar. The app is a Metro app for Windows 8.

I'd like to have some apps in the store when Windows 8 launches; with the way my apps are selling on WP7 with only 2-5 million users, I'd like to think that will explode when sold on Windows which has 1.3 billion users.

But I ran into a few hurdles. First, with [this odd error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783051/why-are-my-xaml-controls-not-showing-up-in-code-behind). Then, with some navigation problems. Finally, with this.

I've been trying to code myself a calendar for a few hours now, and I've realized that for a newbie such as myself it is not as easy as one might think. So I ask the question: Is there anything I can do to make a calendar in Metro? I'm aiming for one that looks something like the one in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYOA1k-nfJI&feature=youtube_gdata) at 2:00.

Are there any controls that are available for such a large calendar?

P.S. I tried

```
this.monthCalendar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar();
```

but that didn't work. Plus, a traditional Windows 7 MonthCalendar would be too small.

Once again, are there any controls that are available to make such a large calendar?